# jquery filter comparing dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, date

I'm currently trying to create a filter that will allow me to select a date using jQueryUI datepicker. This date will then be compared to the value of a hidden input. The parent `div` of the hidden input will then be hidden using `.hide()` function if the hidden date is less than the date select using the picker.

```
<div data-value="I0001-APP0277-S" class="server_wrapper" style="display: block;">
<div class="detail_wrapper">....</div>
<input type="hidden" class="buildStart_hidden" value="4/25/2014 1:46:19 pm">
</div>

<input type="text" id="buildStart_filter" class="secondary_live_filter hasDatepicker">
```

Using this code:

```
$('#buildStart_filter').change(function(){
    var date = $(this).val();
    $('.buildStart_hidden').each(function(){
        if(date>$(this).val().split(' ')[0]){
            $(this).parent().hide();
        }
    });
});
```

But using this code doesn't work. I think it may be due to the comparison of string values rather than date values. What can I change to make the comparison work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more work I have figured out the problem.
I was trying to compare string types and not Date types.

This code is working now as `hiddenDate` and `FilterDate` are `Date()` types and thus can be evaluated using `>=` operator:

```
$('#buildStart_filter').change(function(){
    var filterDate = $('#buildStart_filter').datepicker('getDate');
    $('.buildStart_hidden').each(function(){
        var hiddenDateStr = $(this).val();
        var hiddenDate = new Date(hiddenDateStr);
        if(filterDate>=hiddenDate){
            $(this).parent().hide();    
        }else{
            $(this).parent().show();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

You missing to remove the hour from DATE

```
date.split(' ')[0] > $(this).val().split(' ')[0]
```